# Is there a better way to look up something from a List?

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I've got the following helper function that looks through two lists and based on a field. determines which of the objects in the list to return back. The object being sought is one of 5 types in list A, or one of 2 types in list b ... however, in the event that there is more than one of those types present (which is highly likely) then the types need to be given preference over the others... So if TYPE_4 exists in both list A and B, then the preference needs to be given to the one in list A. Also, if both TYPE_1 and TYPE_2 are present in list A, them preference is given to TYPE_1. IF list B contains TYPE_1, TYPE_2. or TYPE_3, they are not considered at all... only TYPE_4 & TYPE_5 from list B should be considered.

```
private static SomeObject getFavoredObject(
            List<SomeObject> listA,
            List<SomeObject> listb)
    {
        Map<String, SomeObject> typeMap = new HashMap<>();

        listA.forEach(a -> typeMap.put("A " + a.getType(), a));
        listB.forEach(a -> typeMap.put("B " + a.getType(), a));

        if (typeMap.containsKey("A TYPE_1")) {
            return typeMap.get("A Type_1");
        }
        if (typeMap.containsKey("A TYPE_2")) {
            return typeMap.get("A TYPE_2");
        }
        if (typeMap.containsKey("A TYPE_3")) {
            return typeMap.get("A TYPE_3");
        }
        if (typeMap.containsKey("A TYPE_4")) {
            return typeMap.get("A TYPE_4");
        }
        if (typeMap.containsKey("A TYPE_5")) {
            return typeMap.get("A TYPE_5");
        }
        if (typeMap.containsKey("B TYPE_4")) {
            return typeMap.get("B TYPE_4");
        }
        if (typeMap.containsKey("B TYPE_5")) {
            return typeMap.get("B TYPE_5");
        }

        return new Address();
    }
```

What's sticking in my craw is that sequence of if statements... surely there's  much more elegant way of dealing with this. I almost had a solution using a map, where I sorted List A and List B before I added them to the typeMap, but the second I did, the typeMap wasn't sorted... so then I ended up pulling the wrong one (bleh). I've beeb knocking my head against this for a bit over an hour, it's Friday, and it's the end of the day. I'm off to get a beer. If someone can come up with something a bit more elegant that doesn't involve a whole lot of code, reduces the "repeated code" (we use Sonar, and early reports show that this code segment has an issue) or maybe can point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

Comment: what if list a doesn't have `TYPE_1` and `TYPE_2`, and list b does?

Comment: There is an *order* of preference. So the solution is to sort it accordingly, then get the preferred one (standard sorting is ascending, so either get the last one or sort it descending and get the first one). Regular `Map` isn't sorted (you'd need a `SortedMap`), so that's (at least one reason) why your attempt failed.

Comment: @Kayaman - Oh FFS... it was staring at me in the face the whole time. Sometimes you just can't see the forest for the trees. That's what I get for late Friday development after day-long meetings.

Comment: @devReddit - in that case - which is highly likely too - they are ignored. The only types from list B that should be considered are `TYPE_4` and `TYPE_5`.

Answer (score 0):

The central part of the code can be written as a loop over an array.

```
// This array should probably be static and final
// outside this method, assuming a fixed set of keys
String[] keys = {
     "A TYPE_1",  "A TYPE_2", ...
     "B TYPE_4",  "B TYPE_5
 };

 for (String key : keys) 
    if (typeMap.containsKey(key) 
        return typeMap.get(key);
```

Also, assuming SomeObject is never null, I'd avoid the double map access:

```
 for (String key : keys) {
     SomeObject obj = typeMap.get(key);
     if (obj != null) return obj;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a preference list and handle the whole thing based on that:

```
public static final String[] preferences = {"A TYPE_1", "A TYPE_2", "A TYPE_3",
        "A TYPE_4", "A TYPE_5", "B TYPE_4", "B TYPE_5"};
```

You can use a for loop to iterate over these preferences and check whether you can get an available object to return.

```
private static SomeObject getFavoredObject(
        List<SomeObject> listA,
        List<SomeObject> listB) {
    Map<String, SomeObject> typeMap = new HashMap<>();

    listA.forEach(a -> typeMap.put("A " + a.getType(), a));
    listB.forEach(a -> typeMap.put("B " + a.getType(), a));

    SomeObject res = null;
    for (String preference: preferences) {
        res = typeMap.get(preference);
        if (res != null) {
            return res;
        }
    }

    return new SomeObject("");
}
```